Problem about retrieve data from power meter to alert to telegram
my project is retrieve data from power meter and show on dashboard grafana ,i want to customize my message format but value that i want to retrive is not show in preview in notification template value that i want i metadata
this is my template
{{ define "test" }}
  {{- if eq .Status "firing" -}}
    {{- range .Alerts -}}
      {{- $name := .Labels.alertname -}}
      {{- $value := .Annotations.__value_string__ -}}
      {{- if eq $name "Electricity-Cost" -}}
Alertname: {{ .Labels.alertname }}
Cost : {{ .Labels.cost }}
Value : {{ $value }}
      {{- end -}}
    {{- end -}}
  {{- else -}}
There are no alerts
  {{- end -}}
{{ end }}

this is payload
{
    "status": "firing",
    "annotations": {
      "__dashboardUid__": "admg1lokxou80d",
      "__orgId__": "1",
      "__panelId__": "15",
      "__value_string__": "[ var='C0' metric='Electricity-Cost' labels={} value=2.10375654e+06 ]",
      "__values__": "{\"C0\":2103756.54}"
    },
    "labels": {
      "__alert_rule_uid__": "ednq67wwieqkga",
      "__grafana_autogenerated__": "true",
      "__grafana_receiver__": "grafana-alert-telegram",
      "alertname": "Electricity-Cost",
      "cost": "costover",
      "grafana_folder": "energy"
    }

i need to show value in message if value of electricity cost is great than condition it's will alert
